# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded

Tags: php

Good day everyone, I'm trying . This is the code which demonstrates what I'm doing:

```
 <?php
$NoOfGames = 10;
$time = array("06:00:00 " => "07:00:00", "07:00:00" => "08:00:00", "08:00:00" => "09:00:00", "09:00:00" => "10:00:00", "10:00:00" => "11:00:00", "11:00:00" => "12:00:00","12:00:00" => "13:00:00","13:00:00" => "14:00:00","14:00:00" => "15:00:00","15:00:00" => "16:00:00","16:00:00" => "17:00:00","17:00:00" => "18:00:00");

for($i=0;$i<$NoOfGames;$i+1){
    $start_time = array_rand($time);
    $end_time = $time[$start_time];
    $time_new[$start_time] = $end_time;
}
$i =1;
foreach($time_new as $start => $end)
{

    echo  $i. ") ". $start . " to ".  $end . "<br>";
    $i++;
}
?>
```

However, this outputs
[image: it keeps showing this fatal error message]

and I want to display it like this instead

```
1) 17:00:00 to 18:00:00
2) 06:00:00 to 07:00:00
3) 12:00:00 to 13:00:00
4) 11:00:00 to 12:00:00
5) 16:00:00 to 17:00:00
6) 08:00:00 to 09:00:00
7) 13:00:00 to 14:00:00
8) 15:00:00 to 16:00:00
9) 14:00:00 to 15:00:00
10) 09:00:00 to 10:00:00
```

Comment: Use set_time_limit(0) function on top of code. So your code execution will not stop because of time limit.

Comment: You never increase `$i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

Change `$i+1` to `$i++`

The reason is that `$i+1` just evaluates to 1 every time (ie doesn't actually increment `$i`), meaning the loop never exits.

Comment: thank you, but it's show only less than 8 data saved on the array, how to fix it ?

Comment: `$start_time` is a random number. That number is used to set an element in the `$time_new` array. If the same random number turns up more than once, the `$time_new` array element will just be overwritten. So the code as it stands will not always make the same length array for `$time_new`. If what you actually want to do is display 10 items from the first array in a random sequence, consider using `$time_new = $time; shuffle($time_new)` in place of your for loop.